# text data cleaning for NLP

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, data-cleaning

I am having a project in NLP, where I have to clean text data, even though I have done most of it, I am finding it a challenge to clean the following text format.

["data-science"]

After cleaning it should become

["data", "science"]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to remove the special characters using regex, but it is not giving me the desired results.

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt into your question as a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.